# Why can't I use `declare -r` inside a function fo mark a variable readonly while `set -u` is in use?

Tags: bash

With `GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`,

```
#! /bin/bash
set -u

exec {FD1}>tmp1.txt
declare -r FD1
echo "fd1: $FD1"       # why does this work,

function f1() {
  exec {FD2}>tmp2.txt
  readonly FD2
  echo "fd2: $FD2"     # this work,
}

f1

function f2() {
  exec {FD3}>tmp3.txt
  echo "fd3: $FD3"     # and even this work,
  declare -r FD3
  echo "fd3: $FD3"     # when this complains: "FD3: unbound variable"?
}

f2
```

The goal is to make my file descriptor readonly

Comment: This reads as clearly a bug. Tried reporting it to the bash-bugs@gnu.org list?

Comment: `exec {FD1}>tmp1.txt` is new to me, what does that mean? I can't find that syntax in the manual section on redirection.

Comment: From http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html, 2nd paragraph: Each redirection that may be preceded by a file descriptor number may instead be preceded by a word of the form {varname}. In this case ... the shell will allocate a file descriptor greater than 10 and assign it to {varname}

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I usually assume it's my lack of understanding, especially with bash. If I can't resolve it here, I certainly will try the bash-bugs email

Comment: No, its not a bug, `declare` used inside a function indicates local scope

Comment: It turns out @chepner is correct. A conversation with the bug-bash mailing list confirms his answer: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2015-05/msg00003.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's a bug. The `exec` statement assigns a value to the parameter `FD3` in the *global* scope, while the `declare` statement creates a *local* parameter that shadows the global:

> When used in a function, `declare' makes NAMEs local, as with the `local'
>       command.  The `-g' option suppresses this behavior.

It's the local parameter that is undefined. You can see this with a slightly different example:

```
$ FD3=foo
$ f () { FD3=bar; declare -r FD3=baz; echo $FD3; }
$ f
baz   # The value of the function-local parameter
$ echo $FD3
bar   # The value of the global parameter set in f
```